# 500 Internal server error in pyrocms user module

Tags: codeigniter, webserver, php, pyrocms

I have a site in pyrocms 2.0.1 and its working well apart from user module. when i click on Manage user from admin it gives me 500 Internal server error also the usre module is working so slow in local server . we have around 5000 user in the db.here is the configuration file http://www.mypartyaid.com/info.php

Here the entries that appear in the error log

ERROR - 2012-11-29 04:07:08 --> Page Missing: m/style/images/ui-bg_inset-soft_25_000000_1x100.png
ERROR - 2012-11-29 04:07:08 --> Plugin method "baseuri" does not exist on class "Plugin_Url".
ERROR - 2012-11-29 04:07:59 --> Page Missing: robots.txt
ERROR - 2012-11-29 04:07:59 --> Plugin method "baseuri" does not exist on class "Plugin_Url".
ERROR - 2012-11-29 04:08:15 --> Plugin method "baseuri" does not exist on class "Plugin_Url".
ERROR - 2012-11-29 04:08:21 --> Page Missing: m/style/images/ui-bg_inset-soft_25_000000_1x100.png
ERROR - 2012-11-29 04:08:21 --> Plugin method "baseuri" does not exist on class "Plugin_Url".
ERROR - 2012-11-29 04:09:51 --> Page Missing: m/style/images/ui-bg_inset-soft_25_000000_1x100.png
ERROR - 2012-11-29 04:09:51 --> Plugin method "baseuri" does not exist on class "Plugin_Url".
ERROR - 2012-11-29 04:10:35 --> Plugin method "baseuri" does not exist on class "Plugin_Url".
ERROR - 2012-11-29 04:10:35 --> Plugin method "baseuri" does not exist on class "Plugin_Url".
ERROR - 2012-11-29 04:10:35 --> Plugin method "baseuri" does not exist on class "Plugin_Url".
ERROR - 2012-11-29 04:10:38 --> Plugin method "baseuri" does not exist on class "Plugin_Url".
ERROR - 2012-11-29 04:10:38 --> Plugin method "baseuri" does not exist on class "Plugin_Url".
ERROR - 2012-11-29 04:10:39 --> Severity: Notice  --> Undefined index: city

[image]

Server error log

[Thu Nov 29 00:29:33 2012] [warn] [client 141.101.99.77] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning: date(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/New_York' for 'EST/-5.0/no DST' instead in /var/www/vhosts/mypartyaid.com/httpdocs/m/post.php on line 134, referer: http://www.mypartyaid.com/m/post.php?pid=80

[Thu Nov 29 00:32:01 2012] [warn] [client 108.162.222.7] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 45 seconds, referer: http://www.mypartyaid.com/admin

[Thu Nov 29 00:32:01 2012] [error] [client 108.162.222.7] Premature end of script headers: index.php, referer: http://www.mypartyaid.com/admin

[Thu Nov 29 00:35:42 2012] [warn] [client 108.162.222.7] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 45 seconds, referer: http://www.mypartyaid.com/admin

[Thu Nov 29 00:35:42 2012] [error] [client 108.162.222.7] Premature end of script headers: index.php, referer: http://www.mypartyaid.com/admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue ended up not being a server error, it was an inefficiency with the default user model. The module splits the user table into two different tables `default_profiles` and `default_users`. The two tables are then joined using the `user_id` field.

The problem is that many generated SQL statements in the CMS run complex join statements on `default_profiles` causing the query time to increase linearly with the size of the user table.

I put an index on the field `user_id` and the query time for the site's homepage went from 8 seconds to under .001 seconds. Therefore adding an index to this field will allow your user table to scale properly.

Answer (score 1):

A 500 almost ALWAYS indicates a fatal error, but the live site obviously doesn't want to spit out debug data that could lead to your users finding out information they can use to hack the site.

Check your PHP logs and the answer should be pretty obvious. If you can't work it out from that then edit your question to contain the error message from the logs and comment on this question, so I can update my answer.

Comment: I have edited my answer with few error from error log....thanks for your time Phil.

Comment: what is 04:08:15 --> Plugin method "baseuri" does not exist on class "Plugin_Url". ERROR - 2012-11-29 Are you calling {{ uri:baseuri }} in your theme or content somewhere? Because I've never heard of that.

Comment: {{ uri:baseuri }} its used in theme ... Now i have removed this one but i dont think this causing the problem....

Comment: You used a non-existant tag and that caused an error, as is reflected in the logs. Anything else in the logs?

Comment: its by mistake used by the main problem from server side which mentioned above in server errors

Comment: So this is fixed then? I'm not sure what the further problem is, if there is one?